# HasChanged Not Working in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

I'm new to this so I'll try to be clear,
I'm trying to create a single page app with Jquery and AJAX. However, nothing happens, no errors no nothing.

the go to main, second and third are hyperlinks directed to: #/main, #/second, #/third

also, the first.html, second.html, third.html are pages where the data should be retrieved from.

check my code and let me know if there's something wrong with it please:

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
   window.addEventListener('hashchange', function (){
   
    if(window.location.haschange === '#/main'){
    $.get( "first.html", function( data ) {
     $( "#examples" ).html( data );
    })
   }
    
    if(window.location.haschange === '#/second'){
    $.get( "second.html", function( data ) {
     $( "#examples" ).html( data );
    })
   }
    
    if(window.location.haschange === '#/third'){
    $.get( "third.html", function( data ) {
     $( "#examples" ).html( data );
    })
   }
    
  });
 </script>
```

```html
 <## Heading ##html>
<head>
<title>text</title>
</head>
<body>
 <ul>
  <li><button><a href="#/main">Go to Main</button></li>
  <li><button><a href="#/second">Go to Second</button></li>
  <li><button><a href="#/third">Go to Third</button></li>
 </ul>
 
 <div id="examples">
  
 </div>
 
</body>
</html>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
```

Comment: `window.addEventListener('hashchange',` . I think you have a big old typo here.

Comment: And I'm not quite sure `hasChanged` even exists.

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.onhashchange = function(req){ /*your code*/ }`

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach for what you want.

```js
var currentPage = "#main" ;

$('.page').on('click', function(event)
{
    page =  $(event.target).children().first().attr('href') ;
    if ( page != currentPage ) 
    {
        currentPage = page ;
        alert(page) ;
        // your if conditions here 
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<## Heading ##html>
<head>
<title>text</title>
</head>
<body>
 <ul>
  <li><button class="page"><a href="#main">Go to Main</a></button></li>
  <li><button class="page"><a href="#second">Go to Second</a></button></li>
  <li><button class="page"><a href="#third">Go to Third</a></button></li>
 </ul>
 
 <div id="examples">
  
 </div>
 
</body>
</html>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer there was nothing wrong with the code is just that it only supports http server requests, or the other alternative is to use angularJS